# How to debug Golang with build tags in Delve

Tags: debugging, go, visual-studio-code, delve

I am trying to debug Go code with VSCode's Delve. For my testing, I have to run `go test` with tags every time for every test. Above each of my test funtions, I see *run test* and *debug test* options, is there a way to configure **launch.json** so that the tags are added by default?

I have not been able to find relevant documentation on this.

Comment: You can use the `--build-flags '--tags=foo'` to pass tags (or other build flags) to Delve. I don't know anything about VSCode, but if you can fill in flags to `dlv` anywhere then that's what you can use.

Comment: Thanks @MartinTournoij. That was useful.